# Time complexity of a string compression algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity

I tried to do an exercice from cracking the code interview book about compressing a string :

> Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts of
>   repeated characters. For example, the string aabcccccaaa would become
>   a2blc5a3. If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original
>   string, your method should return the original string.

The first proposition given by the author is the following :

```
public static String compressBad(String str) {
    int size = countCompression(str);
    if (size >= str.length()) {
        return str;
    }
    String mystr = "";
    char last = str.charAt(0);
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            mystr += last + "" + count;
            last = str.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return mystr + last + count;
}
```

About the time complexity of thie algorithm, she said that :

> The runtime is 0(p + k^2), where p is the size of the original string and k is the number of character sequences. For example, if the string is aabccdeeaa, then there are six character sequences. It's slow because string concatenation operates in 0(n^2) time

I have two main questions :

1) Why the time complexity is O(p+k^2), it should be only O(p) (where p is the size of the string) no? Because we do only p iterations not p + k^2.

2) Why the time complexity of a string concatenation is 0(n^2)???
I thought that if we have a string3 = string1 + string2 then we have a complexity of size(string1) + size(string2), because we have to create a copy of the two strings before adding them to a new string (create a string is O(1)). So, we will have an addition not a multiplication, no? It isn't the same thing for an array (if we used a char array for example) ?

Can you clarify these points please? I didn't understand how we calculate the complexity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String concatenation is O(n) but in this case it's being concatenated K times.
Every time you find a sequence you have to copy the entire string + what you found. for example if you had four total sequences in the original string
the cost to get the final string will be:

```
(k-3)+ //first sequence
(k-3)+(k-2) + //copying previous string and adding new sequence
((k-3)+(+k-2)+k(-1) + //copying previous string and adding new sequence
((k-3)+(k-2)+(k-1)+k) //copying previous string and adding new sequence
```

Thus complexity is O(p + K^2)